# Как заменить обратный слэш в тексте на символ?

Tags: python

мой код:

```
'12\12\12'.replace('\\', '.')
```

вывод:

```
'12\n\n'
```

а должно:

```
'12.12.12'
```

Comment: В первой строке нет обратного слеша

Comment: У Вас абсолютно рабочий код. Просто в первой строке Вы при записи не применяли экранирование

Comment: В первой строчке у вас используется экранирование, что порождает символы (одинаковый код символа `print(ord('\12'), ord('\n'))  # 10 10`): `print(len('12\12\12'), repr('12\12\12'))  # 4 '12\n\n'`, но это работает только для строк в коде, у которых нет `r` (raw-строки), если бы строка была получена извне из файла, сайта, базы данных и т.п., то там было бы 8 символов

Comment: r'12\12\12'.replace('\\', '.')

Answer (score 0):

```
x = r"12\12\12"
print(x.replace('\\', '.'))   #тут вместо 1 об. слеша 2
```

Comment: В вопросе тоже два слеша. Вы поменяли обычную строку на r-строку, вот у вас и сработало )